Issue with VS code when trying to connect to Salesforce org
I have installed VS code on Apple Silicon Chip M1 and used it for around 1.5 years now without any issues.
I am getting the below error from last week when I try to authorise my Prod or Sandbox orgs.
VS Code is up-to date and Salesforce extensions are all up-to date.
ERROR:

Salesforce Extensions for VS Code encountered a problem while
configuring your environment. Some features might not work. For
details, click Help > Toggle Developer Tools or check the Salesforce
CLI logs in ~/.sfdx/sfdx.log.



You can check this: - Troubleshooting Common Issues, - https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1754

You should have got an update to Salesforce Extension Pack 61.5.0, which is available at least since two days before your post ;-) Have you tried to use the sf command line? Does it work? Have you had a look at the settings of the Salesforce* extensions in VSCode?
